# Leaflet R Package: Possible to control map tile colors/appearance?

Tags: r, google-maps, leaflet, openstreetmap

Wanted to see if anybody had experience controlling the color scheme/appearance of map tiles loaded into the Leaflet package for R.

I know it's possible in the bare javascript implementation of Leaflet, but I haven't found anything within the rstudio.github documentation for the Leaflet R package or elsewhere.

For my specific purpose I'd like to match the color scheme of the map tiles to the color scheme of the website I plan to host the Leaflet app on.  Particularly, specifying colors for roads, water, and land.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: I think the only customisation you can do is change the [provider tiles](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/)

Answer (score 3):

The map is not rendered by Leaflet itself. Instead Leaflet downloads pre-rendered raster [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles). They are just images, usually png, sometimes jpeg.

As already explained by user SymbolixAU you can only choose a different tile provider. [Leaflet provider demo](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) shows various different providers you can use. This is not an exhaustive list, there are various more providers available on the Internet. However keep in mind that each provider has a different tile usage policy and most won't allow you to use their tiles on a heavy-traffic website or to do bulk downloads. And of course there are also [paid-for tile providers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services) available.

Alternatively you can choose to [render your own tiles](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

Answer (score 3):

I've got a Google Maps widget in my `googleway` package that accepts a [`styles`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) argument.

You need a valid API key to use Google

```
library(googleway)

map_key <- "your_api_key"

## style taken from https://snazzymaps.com/
## - paper style
style <- '[{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"hue":"#0066ff"},{"saturation":74},{"lightness":100}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"},{"weight":0.6},{"saturation":-85},{"lightness":61}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#5f94ff"},{"lightness":26},{"gamma":5.86}]}]'

google_map(key = map_key, styles = style)
```

[image]